# How to convert decemial value to hexadecimal int value in java

Tags: java

I have an `int` variable and need to send its hexadecimal value

```
int number1=46;
o/p should be 0x2e;
```

i.e I can store the value int number2=0x2e; the output should not be in string.

Basically I am using it for sending resoponse through buffer which have to be in hex value

```
ChannelBuffer response = ChannelBuffers.directBuffer(2);
response.writeByte(o/p i.e number2);
```

Comment: You are writing the int's bytes into a response buffer. On a byte level, the two values ``46`` and ``0x2e`` are the same. Are you sure you really need to convert it?

Comment: Doesn't implicit casting of the int to a byte work? Just try `response.writeByte(number1)` - given the argument is `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the output should not be a string but that might be not possible. You can assign 0x2e to a int but it will store the decimal value instead.

You can change the hexadecimal string to int and int to hexadecimal like this:

```
//from hexa to decimal
int number = Integer.parseInt(hexaString, 16);
//from decimal to hexadecimal
String hexaString = Integer.toHexString(number);
```

If you provide more details as why you need it in hexadecimal format this answer might change in a update as both values are the same and having 0x2e instead of 46 only affects the visualization.

Edit: I was wrong and found out that you can send the byte value.

```
int number = 0x2e;
byte hex = (byte) number;
```

That way you wont use String and will have it on hexadecimal as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If the output should not be a `String` I suppose it is a simple value. In this case, considering the basis is a non-sens. Values are stored using some coding (whatever is the coding is not important for you). But when you want to set a value to a variable then you can use many different codings/basis. I mean that when you write `17`, `0x11`, `0b10001` the stored value is always the same. When you use the value in some arithmetic operations, the way it is managed is not your concern. When you print the value, then you can choose the output format, but this is because you need to transform a value into a chosen representation.

Think about the way your money is stored in a bank : you can give them coins, checks, etc, but they stored the value in a way you really don't know (probably a simple number somewhere on a hard disk), and when you ask them to make a withdraw they can give you the value in different representations (coins, etc).